# How to clip image in css3 and html5

Tags: html, css

I want to clip image from left and right side with some degree of angle. i have used crip css. but in that i am able to clip in 90 degree only

```
img 
{
position:absolute;
clip:rect(0px,60px,200px,0px);
}
```

is it possible to clip image by 30 degre or more on left and right side.

Comment: Have a look at this http://codepen.io/paul66/pen/turml for some examples of how it can be done - short answer - not easily

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css `mask`, with an image of a rectangle, or with some gradient which looks like a rectangle.

But the more performant way would be to use a wrapping Div, and simply rotate the image inside the div using `transform` while giving `overflow:hidden` to your div. something like that http://jsfiddle.net/gK3XL/

```
img {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(45deg);
    margin: -30px;
}
div {
    -webkit-transform : rotate(-45deg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about [matrix transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform#matrix)?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://dwnloadwallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Final-Fantasy-Rikku.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  width: 540px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: matrix(1, 0, 0.6, 1, 0, 0);
}

.container img {
  transform: matrix(1, 0, -0.6, 1, 0, 0);
}
```

http://codepen.io/raiden-dev/pen/fnjHb?editors=110

Comment: matrix is good nice option, but i am not getting the result which i am looking. i want to clip the image from left in such way that left and right height will be same but angle will be different.like tripezium. i have tried mask,i know in usin svg  is possible but that method is so complex. is there any easy way to do